# Is it possible to re-use @param descriptions in JavaDoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a convenience class for encoding URI's. In it I've created three methods which I use depending on how specific I need to be. I'm wondering if there is a smart way to re-use `@param` descriptions in this case using JavaDoc? (I haven't found any)

```
public class URLCreator {
    public static String getURLString(String host, int port, String path) {
        return getURLString("http", host, port, path, null);
    }
    public static String getURLString(String scheme, String host, int port, String path) {
        return getURLString(scheme, host, port, path, null);
    }
    public static String getURLString(String scheme, String host, int port, String path, String fragment) {
        try {
            URI uri = new URI(scheme, null, host, port, path, null, fragment);
            return uri.toString();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021696/javadoc-reusable-parameter-values

Comment: @MarkButler this one is much more succinct and easier to read though, but you're right

Comment: This is the closest to an answer I could find: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30103339/9768291

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Copying works for overridden, but not for overloaded methods. http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javadoc.html#inheritingcomments

Comment: Yep, I know about the inheritence behavior. I select it as the preferred answer for the "No." part. :-)

Comment: Try the @see tag: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#multiple@see