# Avoiding duplication in JavaDoc comments

Tags: java, documentation, comments, javadoc

I am writing a class where the same xml is used between some methods.

e.g.

```
/**
 * Sample Response:
 * <xmp>
 *      <myXML>
 *          <stuff> data </stuff>
 *      </myXML>
 * </xmp>
 */
 CommonXML Method1();

/**
 * Sample Submission:
 * <xmp>
 *      <myXML>
 *          <stuff> data </stuff>
 *      </myXML>
 * </xmp>
 */
 void Method2(CommonXML xml);
```

I would like to write my documentation so that if the xml changes I have one resource to modify, rather than updating all of the JavaDoc for the affected methods.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: I guess you can specify one class to create it's java-doc. need to Google though. :)

Comment: I think wanting to re-use variable definitions in Javadoc is a common problem. The fact the OP here asks about an XML document hides how common it is - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021696/javadoc-reusable-parameter-values and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036565/is-it-possible-to-re-use-param-descriptions-in-javadoc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not have your documentation read:

```
/**
 * Returns an XML file conforming to the CommonXML schema, available here 
 * (link-to-schema).
 **/
```

Then, if you update your XML, you just update your schema?

Comment: You should end the sentence with a period per the JavaDoc guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

What about using `@see` to refer to the other method?

Answer (score 2):

I would document (under duress - actually i think documentation is a waste of time, as its almost always wrong - use tests to document what your system does) the CommonXML object, rather than each method that takes an object of this type.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to document the CommonXML object (and almost a -1 for thinking documentation is a waste of time.. nothing is more frustrating that debugging code that isn't documented.. reading tests to figure out what the code is supposed to do is far more time-consuming.. documentation is a first-class duty of a developer!)

Comment: As 90% of developers time is allegedly spent reading code, i prefer to spend the "documentation" time refactoring the code, so that its really easy to understand. However i understand that people have strongly held views on that kind of thing!

Comment: The comments are used by consumers of what I produce, so relying on code is not a solution I can work with.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using Javadoc to repeat specifications that are defined elsewhere. *Refer* to the specification.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Doclava](http://code.google.com/p/doclava)'s [include or sample tag](http://code.google.com/p/doclava/wiki/JavadocTags) to do this. These tags copy sample text from an arbitrary file into the output javadoc html. The `@include` tag copies the text verbatim from the given file. The `@sample` tag copies the text from the given file with some modifications.