# How to reuse javadoc for similar functions

Tags: java, javadoc

Let's say I have the following function:

```
/**
 * Thorough explanation
 *
 */
public void somethingImportant(String parameter)
{
   (...)
}
```

Now for convenience, I add the following function:

```
public void somethingImportant()
{
   somethingImportant(null);
}
```

The javadoc for both functions should be next to identical. Perhaps the only difference is that the first function has an extra line describing what `parameter` does.

Is there any way to avoid simply copying the existing javadoc, and instead reusing it?

Comment: I think it depends on your usage. If you use the javadoc to create a docsite a @see should be ok. But if you use them for e.g. inline help in eclipse i would create two distinct javadoc entries.

Comment: Parameter reuse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036565/is-it-possible-to-re-use-param-descriptions-in-javadoc

Comment: @CiroSantilli I don't see the added value of linking that question. What are you trying to say?

Comment: @popovitsj well, reusing the parameters is part of reusing the Javadoc that's all.

Comment: @CiroSantilli but the answer is exactly the same: use the `@see` annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using @see tag and pointing to the original, non-overloaded method?  Then in the overloaded method you can just use the @param value.

```
/**
*@see #yourMethod()
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

This sought of functionality unfortunately isn't supported by JavaDoc. Instead what I do is fully document the method with the most parameters, then link my defaulting methods:

```
/**
 * {@code parameter} defaults to null.
 *
 * @see MyClass#somethingImportant(String)
 */
public void somethingImportant()
```

As an aside; if the methods you are docing are implementations of an interface or an override you can use the `{@inheritDoc}` tag.

Comment: We just need  `@inheritMethod` if type/name is the same, then reuse the comment. Maybe a plugin should work.